# Print sqlite query to logCat

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, logcat

Is there a way to print my sqlite query to logCat? Here is my query

```
db.query(TABLE, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null)
```

Comment: @beetlej @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh: What if I don't have a cursor but instead did a `getContentResolver().delete(...)`? I am not looking for the log of the result. I am looking for the SQLite string itself. @tinysunlight got the idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can Try to add

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog V
adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements V
```

For ormlite

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.StatementExecutor VERBOSE 
adb shell setprop log.tag.BaseMappedStatement VERBOSE 
adb shell setprop log.tag.MappedCreate VERBOSE 
adb shell setprop log.tag.ORMLite DEBUG
```

You may need to restart Android Studio.

**Edit 1:**
I test sqllite on Mobile, the configs seem useless.I don't know the reason.
It doesn't work as the source code say:

```
public final class SQLiteDebug {
    private static native void nativeGetPagerStats(PagerStats stats);

    /**
     * Controls the printing of informational SQL log messages.
     *
     * Enable using "adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteLog VERBOSE".
     */
    public static final boolean DEBUG_SQL_LOG =
            Log.isLoggable("SQLiteLog", Log.VERBOSE);

    /**
     * Controls the printing of SQL statements as they are executed.
     *
     * Enable using "adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteStatements VERBOSE".
     */
    public static final boolean DEBUG_SQL_STATEMENTS =
            Log.isLoggable("SQLiteStatements", Log.VERBOSE);

    /**
     * Controls the printing of wall-clock time taken to execute SQL statements
     * as they are executed.
     *
     * Enable using "adb shell setprop log.tag.SQLiteTime VERBOSE".
     */
    public static final boolean DEBUG_SQL_TIME =
            Log.isLoggable("SQLiteTime", Log.VERBOSE);

    /**
     * True to enable database performance testing instrumentation.
     * @hide
     */
    public static final boolean DEBUG_LOG_SLOW_QUERIES = Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE;

    private SQLiteDebug() {
    }
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not getting any results with this approach. Since I am using sqlite I use the two first lines following tab `Help >> Configure Debug Log Settings`

Comment: As far as i could see, this class doesn't exist today? Try referencing android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDebug, it is not resolved

Answer (score 3):

use this line to display

```
Log.d(TAG, DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
```

Answer (score 2):

Android has a utility class to dump cursor! Just like below:

```
while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Log.e(TAG,DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRowToString(cursor));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would read through each line read by the query, and print value from each line to the logcat using:

```
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    /* Reading values from the current line, putting them into variables */
    ...

    /* Print the log message */
    Log.d("Log message", value1 + " and " + value2 + " and " + ... );

    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```